# Adding an array to sessionstorage sharepoint list

Tags: list, javascript

```
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listTitle.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
    listUrl.push(oListItem.get_item('PrivacyStatementUrls').get_url()); 
    listIsActive.push(oListItem.get_item('IsActive'));
    listOrder.push(oListItem.get_item('SortOrder'));

}
sessionStorage.setItem('Title', listTitle);
sessionStorage.setItem('Url', listUrl);
sessionStorage.setItem('IsActive', listIsActive);
sessionStorage.setItem('Order', listOrder);
```

Here is my code for adding an array to sessionstorage. When outputting the array from session storage it seems to output a letter at a time but when I output the array without session storage it outputs the whole valu

Comment: How are you outputting from session storage?

Comment: sessionStorage.Title[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session storage saves everything in string format.
In order to use session storage with our array, we'll need to convert our array into a string using a method that makes it easy for us to unconvert later. The way convert an array into a string is by using the JSON stringify function.

Check following example:

```
var movies = ["Reservoir Dogs", "Pulp Fiction", "Jackie Brown", 
              "Kill Bill", "Death Proof", "Inglourious Basterds"];

localStorage.setItem("quentinTarantino", JSON.stringify(movies));
```

To retrieve:

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("quentinTarantino");
var movies2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/storing_and_retrieving_an_array_from_local_storage.htm